# Sci-fi short story about kids living in the slums of a futuristic world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, arthurian

Looking for a short story that was in an anthology I read in the early 2000s.

Set in a futuristic world and told from POV of a girl who lives in the slums with a bunch of other kids. The main leader of the kids is charismatic and good (King Arthur) and one day a rich lady offers to take him off-planet to a better life. He refuses and dies later (of sickness, maybe?), but the narrator and another kid cover up his death and tell the others he went with the lady and will one day return to save them all.

I don't remember any of the other stories except for one about a rat creature that lived underground and was looking for help?

Comment: Was the legend of King Arthur explicitly mentioned in the story?

Comment: I don't remember, but it might have been mentioned in a "old earth story about a king" kind of way